# R ggplot2: Title and legend in one line

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I align the title and legend in one line in `ggplot2 2.2.0`?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dfr <- data.frame(x=factor(1:20),y1=runif(n=20)) %>%
  mutate(y2=1-y1) %>%
  gather(variable,value,-x)

ggplot(dfr,aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  labs(title="Badass title")+
  theme(legend.position="top",
        legend.justification="right")
```

Changing the `lineheight` and/or `vjust` as title property doesn't seem to do anything.

```
ggplot(dfr,aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  labs(title="Badass title")+
  theme(legend.position="top",
        legend.justification="right",
        plot.title = element_text(lineheight=-5,vjust=0))
```

Comment: Maybe add `theme(plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(0,0,0,0, "line")), legend.box.margin = margin(-1,0,0,0, "line"))`?

Answer (score 7):

Hardly perfect, but something like this will work:

```
ggplot(dfr,aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  labs(title="Badass title")+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(direction = "horizontal")) +
  theme(legend.position=c(1, 1.05),
        legend.justification="right")
```

[image]